# Python error: 'list' object is not callable after converting the map function to list

Tags: python, list, callable

The following codes showed I tried to map a function list and got a type error of "'`list`' object is not callable".

The L1 is of type '`map`', so I used list function to convert it and it still returned an error.

Do you have any idea about this problem? Thanks!

```
import math
func_list=[math.sin, math.cos, math.exp]
result=lambda L: map(func_list, L)
L=[0,0,0]
L1=result(L)
for x in L1:
    print(x)
```

the type of result is `<class 'function'>` the type of result is `<class 'map'>`

```
Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-22-17579bed9240> in <module>
          6 print("the type of result is " + str(type(result)))
          7 print("the type of result is " + str(type(L1)))
    ----> 8 for x in L1:
          9     print(x)
    
    TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: `map` expects a function as its first argument, but `[math.sin, math.cos, math.exp]` is not a function, it's a list. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: This question is to calculate the math(sin(0)), math(sin(0)), math(sin(0)) with a function list and lambda function. Thank you for clarifying this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation for the `map(function, iterable)` function:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

But you pass list to the `function` parameter.

So your example can be replaced with the next code e.g.:

```
import math

func_list = [math.sin, math.cos, math.exp]

result=lambda L: map(lambda x: map(lambda func: func(x), func_list), L)

L = [0, 0, 0]
L1 = result(L)

for x in L1:
    for value in x:
        print(value, end=' ')
    
    print()
```

Comment: @AmyZeng  L list is a set of different values or you just want to calculate different functions for one value?

Comment: it is to calculate [math.sin(0), math.cos(0), math.exp(0)] with a function list and with map function. The values assigned to sin/cos/exp should be changable.

Comment: @AmyZeng, okay, then this solution makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The below seems like a shorter way to get the same result.

```
import math
func_list=[math.sin, math.cos, math.exp]
lst = [f(0) for f in func_list]
print(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you, it is neat, while this is an coding exercise that requires "map" and "lambda" expressions to be in the codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import math

 func_list = [math.sin, math.cos, math.exp]

 result=lambda L: map(lambda x: map(lambda func: func(x), func_list), L)

 L = [0, 0, 0]
 L1 = result(L)

 for x in L1:
 for value in x:
    print(value, end=' ')

 print()
```